# Nginx redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, nginx

I am facing a weird problem in redirecting using nginx.

I am transferring the .htaccess rules from our existing server apache to nginx, and while I am able to transfer almost all the rules, one rule is not working for me:

**HTAccess**:

```
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)-viewReview.html$ viewReview.php?brand=$1&model=$2 [QSA,L]
```

**Nginx-Rule**

```
rewrite ^/(.*)-(.*)-viewReview.html$ /viewReview.php?brand=$1&model=$2 last;
```

This, rule is not working for this input:

```
http://testsite.com/Asus-Fonepad+7+8GB+3G-viewReview.html
```

This seems to be a problem with the "+" that is present in the  URL. As this URL works fine and redirects properly for the following example:

```
http://testsite.com/Asus-E600-viewReview.html
```

Any pointers on how to handle the "+" in URL.

The case is exactly similar as the question mentioned here:         https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2493497, I can handle the case in code, but that would require a change in large number of files, and basically we will be decoding it twice, can anyone here elaborate more on how we can do it nginx?

Thanks,
Nitesh

Comment: `write-review` != `viewReview`

Comment: Sorry, copied incorrect link, corrected now.

Comment: This should work. The only thing is that `+` will be replaced with space.

Comment: Thanks, then the problem is that as the "+" is replace by "". The php script is thus not working correctly (getting unexpected input) and throwing an error. Any way to keep the "+".

Comment: Well, replace space back to `+`. Or pass original URL to PHP and parse it there.

Comment: I also checked the redirect link: It is redirecting to: http://testsite.com/viewReview.php?brand=Asus&model=Fonepad%2b7%2b8GB%2b3G instead of http://testsite.com/viewReview.php?brand=Asus&model=Fonepad+7+8GB+3G. Basically converting "+" to "%2b", what will be the best way to handle this?

Comment: `%2b` is urlencoded `+` and shoud be automatically decoded by PHP

Comment: It is not working so somehow decoding is not working in the PHP code :). As I am not sure of the particular piece of code and it works well in apache, can I do something in nginx?